# Unexpected datetime value is inserted into Task ReminderDateTime field

Tags: apex, task-notifications

I am using the Apex code to create a task. During the task creation i set the ReminderDateTime same as the task due date, however, i am seeing the following confusing behaviors, i think it is related to how it is inserted and the timezone setting, but not sure how to solve it.

```
    Datetime createdDate = System.now();
    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT ID, Name, IsDefault, IsActive From BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true ];
    Datetime  dueDate = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, createdDate ,60000 * 60 *24 *2);

                System.debug(dueDate);

   Approver__c approver = [SELECT User__c from Approver__c where Department__c =: cdp.Approval_Status__c];

    if (cdp.Approval_Status__c != 'BA VP' && cdp.Approval_Status__c != 'CEO' && approver !=null ){ 
        Date taskDueDate =  Date.newInstance(dueDate.year(), dueDate.month(), dueDate.day())   ;

        System.debug(taskDueDate);

        Task ts  = new  Task ();        
        ts.ActivityDate =  taskDueDate;
        ts.Priority = 'High';
        ts.WhatId = cdp.Id;
        ts.OwnerId = approver.user__c;
        ts.subject = cdp.Approval_Status__c + ' CDP Review Task'; 
        ts.Description = 'Please review CDP ' + cdp.CDP_Name__c + ' within 2 business day. When it is done, please mark the task as done. Thank you!';

        ts.IsReminderSet = true;
        ts.ReminderDateTime =  dueDate ;

        insert ts;
```

Debugging log shows:
[image]

the query shows:
[image]

The Reminder Date Time in the task page shows:
[image]

So there are 3 different days. How can I have the Reminder DateTime set and displayed as what debug log shows?

Comment: Can you see any other processes occurring when the Task is inserted? To go from UTC 2019-12-04 14:29:00 to a value of Nov 30, 2019 at 7 pm in the users UI is way to big a jump to be explained my timezone differences. Something else is intentionally changing the value. Do you have any triggers or other automation on Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

These are the same times. DateTime.now() returns the current time **in GMT**. This will be adjusted to the user's time zone when displayed in the system. You'll need to adjust the time by the user's timezone offset.

```
ts.ReminderDateTime =  dueDate.addSeconds(-(UserInfo.getTimeZone().getOffset(dueDate)/1000));
```

We have to invert the time offset because we need to move in the opposite direction to get the right offset from GMT (e.g. -05:00 means we need to *add* five hours to get to GMT). Also, this value is in milliseconds, hence we divide by 1000.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but doesn't make a difference.